# Java Logger wont log

Tags: java, logging

Was able to print some stuff in the logfile by studying and modifying some sample codes but while running the package nothing is being printed to the logfile.

Main Class (Client.java)

```
public class Client {
    static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName());
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client logger = new Client();

        try {
            LogSetup.setup();
            emsSession = logger.Initialise();
            logger.getAllMEInfo();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Problems with creating the log files");
        }

    }

    private void getAllMEInfo() {
       LOGGER.setLevel(Level.INFO);
       LOGGER.severe("Info Log");
       LOGGER.warning("Info Log");
       LOGGER.info("Info Log");
       LOGGER.finest("Really not important");
       // Some codes for the method
    }
}
```

LogSetup.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler;
import java.util.logging.FileHandler;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class LogSetup {
    static private FileHandler fileTxt;
    static private LogWriter formatterTxt;

    static public void setup() throws IOException, ParseException {
        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Logger.GLOBAL_LOGGER_NAME);
        Logger rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
        Handler[] handlers = rootLogger.getHandlers();

        if (handlers[0] instanceof ConsoleHandler) {
            logger.removeHandler(handlers[0]);
        }

        logger.setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
        fileTxt = new FileHandler(LogFile.txt");

        // create a TXT formatter
        formatterTxt = new LogWriter();
        fileTxt.setFormatter(formatterTxt);
        logger.addHandler(fileTxt);

    }

}
```

LogWriter.java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Formatter;
import java.util.logging.Handler;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;

class LogWriter extends Formatter {
    public String format(LogRecord rec) {
        System.out.println("RECORDING..............");
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer(1000);
        buf.append(rec.getLevel());
        buf.append(calcDate(rec.getMillis()));
        buf.append(formatMessage(rec));
        return buf.toString();
    }

    private String calcDate(long millisecs) {
        SimpleDateFormat date_format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy HH:mm\n");
        Date resultdate = new Date(millisecs);
        return date_format.format(resultdate);
    }

    public String getHead(Handler h) {
        return ("START " + new Date()) + "\n";
    }

    public String getTail(Handler h) {
        return "END " + new Date() + "\n";
    }
}
```

Log prints the START and END but doesn't even enter in the buff ""RECORDING.............."" so basically nothing is being logged. Any idea???

Comment: Which framework do you use ? slf4j ? log4j ? java.util.logging ?

Comment: I think OP is using `java.util.logging`

Comment: java.util.logging. I added the #includes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Please put include statements in your examples so others can try your code.*

If you are using `java.util.logging`, try moving to logback.  Logback logging will log properly with no configuration.  If you are using java.util.logging then you'll need to find a tutorial on how to configure it, as if it's not configured it doesn't log like you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

The logging framework use a configuration file, where u can set "where and what" to output, for java.util.logging the configuration file is under the folder lib of ure current jvm "/jdk1.x.x/jre/lib/logging.properties" I share my link the problem is in spanish [config logging](http://rbeltrand.wordpress.com/2013/01/29/java-logging-logger-y-netbeans-configuracion/)

In short words search the next line and change INFO -> ALL

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=INFO
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL

In your code u only need to log message u want, ex:

```
public class TestLog {
    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestLog.class.getName());
    public static void doLog() {
        log.info("info log");
        log.fine("fine log");
        log.finer("finer log");
        .....
        log.severe("severe log");
    }
}
```

Always try to use fine, finer or finest for ure debug message, don't use INFO because always print on default config and can slow ure application